# class org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultClassFinder$InfoBuildingVisitor has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I changed struts2 version form 2.5.2 to 2.5.10.1 and I have started getting this error. Looks like the new version is not reading any of the action classes. Do I need to change any other library with it. My app starts up properly but I see this log in the console.

Stack trace:

```
ERROR DefaultClassFinder Unable to read class [mig.esign.admin.action.appprops.AppPropertiesAction]
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultClassFinder$InfoBuildingVisitor has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultClassFinder.readClassDef(DefaultClassFinder.java:459)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultClassFinder.<init>(DefaultClassFinder.java:90)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildClassFinder(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:397)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:379)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:335)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:199)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:906)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR DefaultClassFinder Unable to read class [mig.esign.admin.action.BaseAction]
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/apache/struts2/convention/DefaultClassFinder$InfoBuildingVisitor
at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultClassFinder.readClassDef(DefaultClassFinder.java:459)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultClassFinder.<init>(DefaultClassFinder.java:90)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildClassFinder(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:397)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:379)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:335)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:199)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:906)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR DefaultClassFinder Unable to read class [mig.esign.admin.action.client.ClientAction]
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/apache/struts2/convention/DefaultClassFinder$InfoBuildingVisitor
at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultClassFinder.readClassDef(DefaultClassFinder.java:459)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultClassFinder.<init>(DefaultClassFinder.java:90)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildClassFinder(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:397)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:379)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:335)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:199)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:906)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR DefaultClassFinder Unable to read class [mig.esign.admin.action.clientexport.ClientExportAction]
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/apache/struts2/convention/DefaultClassFinder$InfoBuildingVisitor
at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultClassFinder.readClassDef(DefaultClassFinder.java:459)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultClassFinder.<init>(DefaultClassFinder.java:90)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildClassFinder(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:397)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:379)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:335)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:199)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:906)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: _"I changed struts2 version form 2.5.2 to 2.5.10.1"_ -- did you change it _EVERYWHERE_?  I.e. is the version on your deployment server also updated to 2.5.10.1? This type of error is usually caused by building against one version and deploying against a different version.

Comment: Did you update plugins' version?

Comment: @ Roman. Yes I just changed the pom then I updated my project using Maven.

Comment: @Jim, it's running in my local, and yes the jar is being updated in the tomcat server in my local.

Comment: I know you think they're the same but `IncompatibleClassChangeError` strongly hints at a version incompatibility. In one version the interface was changed to a superclass (or vice versa).  You should search your entire system for the jar file and ensure that only one version is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I had struts2-convention plugin which was creating this incompatibility issue. I removed the entire plugin since I didn't need it anymore with the newer version of struts2 and the app started working perfectly without any runtime errors.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is jar incompatibility.

Struts2 convention Plugin(2.5.10) has compilation dependency it's using `asm-5.1, asm-commons-5.1, asm-tree-5.1` jars. So If you are using weblogic server add

```
<wls:package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>
```

in your `weblogic.xml`.